# html5 database syntax error in insert where statement using gwt-html5-database

Tags: sql, html, gwt

How should a correct `INSERT WHERE` statement look like?
I have a normal `INSERT` statement which looks like this and it works:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Vocables (english, german) VALUES (?, ?)", new Object[]{eng, ger}, new StatementCallback<JavaScriptObject>()
```

But how should look like an `INSERT WHERE` statement?
I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
("INSERT INTO Vocables (english, german) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE id=(?)", new Object[]{eng, ger,id});
```

I get this error message:

```
could not prepare statement(1 near "WHERE": syntax error)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `WHERE` clause in `INSERT` command...

> how should look like a correct INSERT WHERE statement?

Without `WHERE` ...

Comment: @Pero. You need to filter the rows you're adding to the table **before** the `insert`

Comment: i think UPDATE is the best solution

Comment: @Pero. It depends in what you're trying to do... (It might be the only solution or not a solution at all)

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into Vocables 
    select column1, column2 from other_table where ...
```